# Calling a Go string function from Python ctypes results in segfault

Tags: python, go, ctypes, ffi

I have a module called `test.go` that contains two simple Go functions which accept string types:

```golang
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "C"
)

//export TestConcat
func TestConcat(testArg string, testArg2 string) (string) {
  retval := testArg + testArg2
  return retval
}

//export TestHello
func TestHello(testArg string) {
  fmt.Println("%v\n", testArg)
}


func main(){}
```

I compile it as a shared library with `go build -o test.so -buildmode=c-shared test.go`

Then I have a Python module called `test.py`

```py
import ctypes

from ctypes import cdll


test_strings = [
    "teststring1",
    "teststring2"
]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("./test.so")
    lib.TestConcat.argtypes = [ctypes.c_wchar_p, ctypes.c_wchar_p]
    lib.TestHello.argtypes = [ctypes.c_wchar_p]
    for test_string in test_strings:
        print(
            lib.TestConcat("hello", test_string)
        )
        lib.TestHello(test_string)
```

Then I run `test.py` and get a nasty segfault

```
runtime: out of memory: cannot allocate 279362762964992-byte block (66781184 in use)
fatal error: out of memory
```

I've tried wrapping the arguments in `ctypes.c_wchar_p` to no avail.

What am I doing wrong here? And specifically, how does one interact with Go functions that accept string arguments in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Go's `string` type is actually something like

```golang
type string {
    ptr *byte
    size int
}
```

so that is what the `Test{Hello|Concat}` actually expect—not a pair of pointers but a pair of `struct`-typed values.
In other words, `cgo` performs just enough magic to gateway calls from Go to C and back, but it does not perform automatic conversions of values.

You have two options:

- Explicitly work with this from your `ctypes` bindings, if possible.
  When compiling your package, `cgo` generates a header file which contains a C definition for the struct representing a Go string; you could use it right away.
- Make the functions exported to C compatible with the C's "type system".
  For this, `cgo` offers [helper functions `C.CString` and `C.GoString`](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/#hdr-Go_references_to_C).
  Basically, you can define your API like this:

  ```golang
  func TestHello(a, b *C.char) *C.char {
      testArg1, testArg2 := C.GoString(a), C.GoString(b)
      return C.CString(testArg + TestArg2)
  }
  ```

  Note few caveats here:

  - Both of these helpers copy the memory of their argument, so the silly example above would work just fine but it would first duplicate the memory blocks pointed to by `a` and `b`, then eat up twice as much memory to produce the concatenated string and then copy the memory of the resulting string once again to produce the returned pointer.
    IOW, this approach is fine if you're trying to export to C some big chunk of Go code so that these allocations are dwarfed by whatever that chunk does.
  - Using `*C.char` is the same as `*char` in C, so the string is expected to be NUL-terminated; if it's not, use `C.GoStringN`.
  - Every memory block allocated by `C.CString` have to be freed by a call to `C.free`. And here's a twist: `C.free` is basically a thin shim to call `free()` from the linked in `libc`, so if you can guarantee the complete product (the code fully loaded into memory and (inter)linked using the dymanic linker) has only a single copy of `libc` linked in, you can call `free()` from the non-Go code on the memory blocks produced by calls to `C.Cstring` in the Go code.

A few more random pointers:

- I'm not well-versed in Python's `ctypes` but I'd speculate using `ctypes.c_wchar_p` is not correct: in C (and C++, FWIW) `wchar_t` is a type to denote a single *fixed-sized* "wide character", which is *usually* a [UCS-2/UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) code point, and Go's strings are not composed of these—they may contain arbitrary bytes, and when they are used to contain Unicode text, they are encoded using [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) which is a multi-byte ecoding (a single Unicode code point may be represented by 1 to 4 bytes in the string).
  In either case, `wchar_t` cannot be used for UTF-8 (and actually [many seasoned devs beleive it's an abomination](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/102215/303695)).
- Please read [the docs on `cmd/cgo`](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/) *completely* before embarking on this project. Really, please do!